# 2 function save() to one model

Tags: python, django

I need add 2 function save() to one model. How to do?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Property, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.key = ''.join(random.choice(string.letters) for i in xrange(132))
    ..........
    return self
```

Comment: Why do you need this? I suspect you're trying to do something unrelated to actual saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Even if they have two different signatures it is not possible to have two functions with the same name in Python (and in your case they hardly have a signature).

You can either do:

```
def save(self, which_save, *args, **kwargs):
    if(which_save == 1):
        do_something()
    elif(which_save == 2):
        do_something_else()
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

or two different names:

```
def save_a(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # some code

def save_b(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # some other code
```

or you can mix the two - have `save`, `save_a` and `save_b`.

Comment: Ok. I have save_a(..) and save_b(..). How to run this? Now not working

Comment: If you are using Django's admin it will not work as it probably tries to call `.save()`. But from your code you should be able to call the two saves (don't forget to call `super(Property, self).save`.